# How to convert string of collections to collections

Tags: grails, groovy

How to convert string of collections to collections

example variables:

```
string_txt = "[id:2,name:'myname',age:'20']"
```

i want use it as instances:

```
string_txt.id >> 2
string_txt.name >> "myname"
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Eval` class:

```
def stringTxt = "[id:2,name:'myname',age:'20']"
def map = Eval.me( stringTxt )
assert map.name == 'myname'
```

Of course, if there's another way of doing it other than putting the Map into a String, you should probably do that.  Evaluating text has the potential to be a large security risk :-(